# How to get Month from Date?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a month from a cell that contains a date? I'm trying to do the following. But it throws a Run-time error #13 that the types don't match. How would you go about doing this, I've tried many solutions but it just doesn't work.

In my stylesheet I have this [where I put start and end values and have blank spaces for the Macro to write in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HptoS.png)

```
Sub Search()

Dim accountTxt As String
Dim propertyTxt As String
Dim startMonth As Integer
Dim endMonth As Integer

Dim iAccount As String
Dim iProperty As String

Dim acum As Integer
Dim rowMonth As Integer

accountTxt = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 17).Text
propertyTxt = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 17).Text

startMonth = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 17).Value
endMonth = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 17).Value

For i = 1 To 800
    iAccount = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value
    iProperty = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
    rowMonth = Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)

    If rowMonth >= startMonth And rowMonth <= endMonth Then
        If InStr(1, iAccount, accountTxt) Then
                Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                acum = acum + Cells(i, 12).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i
Cells(8, 17).Value = acum
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming the cell contains a Date (and not just text that looks like a date), use `Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2)` (or even `Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)` or even `Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1))`) instead of `Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text)`

Comment: You should also change `propertyTxt = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 17).Value` to `endMonth = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 17).Value` so that `endMonth` is not zero.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'll look into that and let you know.

Comment: Also, your type mismatch was probably caused by a cell somewhere within A1:A800 not being displayed as a valid date (possibly a blank cell?).  A blank cell, for instance, would have caused your `Month(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text)` to be equivalent to `Month("")` which will cause a type mismatch.

Comment: So the problem was that I forgot to add +1 to the iterator so it was first reading the table heading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have something in **B9** like:

[image]

It may be a real date or just a string that looks like a date.  In either case:

```
Sub PerhapsADate()
    Dim s As String, MonthAsNumber As Long
    Dim MonthAsString As String

    s = Range("B9").Text

    MonthAsNumber = --Split(s, "/")(0)
    MonthAsString = Format(CDate(s), "mmmm")

    MsgBox MonthAsNumber & vbCrLf & MonthAsString
End Sub
```

will get the month as both a number or a string:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using DatePart instead of split or another text parsing solution: `MonthAsNumber = DatePart("m", s)` since it is applicable/useful/preferred in other realms (C#, C++, SQL, VB).

Comment: @n8.  **Good call** ................ `DatePart()` seems to handle a variety of formats as well.

Comment: Right, it responds to the datatype.  Flexibility.

Comment: @n8.  Please consider posting a separate answer...........your valuable suggestion will benefit many VBA users.

Comment: Didn't want to step on your toes, but I done did it!

Answer (score 1):

To parlay off of Gary's Student's answer:

```
Sub PerhapsADate()
    Dim s As Date, MonthAsNumber As Long
    Dim MonthAsString As String

    s = Range("B9").Text

    MonthAsNumber = DatePart("m", s)
    MonthAsString = Format(s, "mmmm")

    MsgBox MonthAsNumber & vbCrLf & MonthAsString
End Sub
```

This solution differs slightly in that typing "s" as a date forces the text to be recognized as a date and therefore will be less prone to failure where international date format standards vary.

Comment: Nice! ............the cool thing about adding alternative approaches is that it both gives the Poster options and increases the tutorial value of the post to the general community of users.

Answer (score 0):

I got a type mismatch because the iterator starts reading the Date column at the "Date" heading and not the date value (e.g. 01-10-2017)

Comment: Please comment on the answer, please do not answer your own question in an attempt to discuss a solution.  Keep in mind that it's ok to answer your own question if you have a better solution, though.